# Which types of files can images.get_serving_url() serve?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm interested to know which types of files can be served by GAE's image server.

Or better yet, the location of a list/tuple of these types stored in the library somewhere (to automatically support future formats).

Answer (score 1):

While Java library offers `Enum Image.Format` [listing](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/Image.Format.html#values%28%29) all the Image formats usable by the images api, Python does not seem to offer this kind of information.

Looking at the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=it#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/images/images_stub.py&q=package%3ahttp://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&d=0), the list of supported image format is hardcoded as for example:

```
if img_format not in ("BMP", "GIF", "ICO", "JPEG", "PNG", "TIFF"):
      raise apiproxy_errors.ApplicationError(
          images_service_pb.ImagesServiceError.NOT_IMAGE)
```

It looks like a legit reason to file a new [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry).